# Installing xv6 on linux mint 16 x64

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-mint, xv6

I'm having an error when trying to *make* xv6 on linux mint 16 64bit.
It is a new installation of the linux mint and thus I might be missing of some libraries, I just can't find out which..
This is the error:

```
gcc -m32 -Werror -Wall -o mkfs mkfs.c
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [mkfs] Error 1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try installing multilib by typing `sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib` in your shell.

Comment: That did it! that was what I was missing! Thanks